# Difference between encrypting a file vs its content

Tags: file, encryption, cryptography

I know this is a duplicate: [Is file encryption different from content encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227335/is-file-encryption-different-from-content-encryption)

But, none of the answers in the duplicate are accepted(*not that would be an indication of correctness really*) nor any upvoted answer seems to weigh above the other. So, it seems we are back to square one.

I have a text file and would like to know if there is a difference between encrypting the contents vs the file. Would the answer differ for other kind of files?

Comment: If you have a file, then encrypting the file means encrypting the contents of the file. If you have a TV broadcast (which is a type of content), and you encrypt it, you get an encrypted TV broadcast, but there is no file encryption, as there is no file. If you encrypt part of the file content, you have also not encrypted the file. Note though that in general this is not a question about programming, but about English language semantics, more or less equivalent to "difference between eating lunch and eating lunch food".

Comment: Slightly complicating the matter is the fact that "content" and "contents" can and do mean different things, and both your question and my answer liberally switched between the two.